# Vue.js: Target other div than the bound one within vue object

Tags: javascript, leaflet, vue.js

I'm using Vue and Leaflet for displaying polygons (zones) on a map and display appropriate information (messages) about the specific polygons after clicking on them on the map. The div, where I render the messages in, has the id "**#messagearea**" and is bound to the "**el**" object. To display the appropriate messages, I am dependant on the "Zone-id".
Now I also want to display information into another div with a **different id**. I am also dependant on the "Zone-id" here, so I would like to do this in the same Vue. If I would create another Vue, I would have to render the Leaflet map again to write another **polygon.on('click',...)** function, which displays appropriate information for the polygons. What is the most elegant and/or easiest way to realize this?
Here my vue object:

```
var mapVue = new Vue({
    el: '#messagearea',
    data: {
        function() {
            return {
                map: false
            };
        },
        zones: [],
        messages: [],
    },
    ready: function () {
        this.map = L.map('map').setView([51.959, 7.623], 14);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(this.map);
        this.$http.get('/api/zones', function (data) {
            this.$set('zones', data);
            for (var i = 0; i < this.zones['Zones'].length; i++) {
                polygon = L.polygon(
                    this.zones['Zones'][i]['Geometry']['Coordinates']).addTo(this.map);
                polygon.bindPopup(this.zones['Zones'][i]['Name']);
                polygon.on('click', messageCallback(i))
              // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ADD THE FUNCTION FOR THE OTHER DIV
            }
            function messageCallback(i) {
                return function () {
                    mapVue.getMessages(mapVue.zones['Zones'][i]['Zone-id']);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    methods:
    {
        getMessages: function (id) {
            this.$http.get('/api/messages?zone=' + id, function (data) {
                console.log("messages called");
                this.$set('messages', data['Messages']);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: If you are using a version of Vue from 1.0.22 you can use [extends](http://vuejs.org/api/#extends), so in the other component just change the target `el` selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by making use of **Vue.component()**, the **vue.$dispatch()** and **vue.$broadcast()** functions. I just dispatched the zone id to a parent component and then delivered it with the broadcast function to all child components, which are in need of the zone id. Displaying the appropriate messages was no problem then anymore.